# Python: Como aplicar mock em dataclass?

Tags: python-3.x, testes-de-unidade, mock, data-class

Tenho seguinte código :

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Config:
    system: str = platform.system().lower()

class TestConfig(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Config_linux(self):
        system = 'linux'
        with mock.patch('platform.system', return_value=system), \
                mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'INCOLUMEPY_SYSTEM': system}):

            op_cfg = configure.Config()
            self.assertEqual(system, op_cfg.system)

    def test_Config_win(self):
        system = 'windows'
        with mock.patch('platform.system', return_value=system), \
                mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'INCOLUMEPY_SYSTEM': system}):
            config()
            op_cfg = configure.Config()
            self.assertEqual(system, op_cfg.system)

    def test_Config_mac(self):
        system = 'mac'
        with mock.patch('platform.system', return_value=system), \
                mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'INCOLUMEPY_SYSTEM': system}):
            op_cfg = configure.Config()
            self.assertEqual(system, op_cfg.system)
```

Neste caso específico a instancia dataclass, ignora os parametros passados via mock e lê o sistema operacional.

Como posso contornar esta situação?

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o corpo de classes são executados no momento de interpretação do arquivo, e você faz o mock depois disso ter acontecido (tarde demais). Minha sugestão é que faça ao mock diretamente da sua dataclass:

```
with patch.object(Config, 'system', 'linux'):
    print(Config.system)  # linux
```